# How can I update a property's value after changing it's input value in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lambda, interface, properties

I have this interface `IHasCooldown` with these properties:

```
int Id { get; }
float CooldownDuration { get; }
```

In another class (let's call `Attack`), I set the `Id` as the `atkId` and the `CooldownDuration` as `attackCooldown`. The `attackCooldown` being a property so it can be changed.

```
public float attackCooldown { get; set; }
int atkId = 2;
public int Id => atkId;
public float CooldownDuration => attackCooldown;
```

Finally, in class `SubAttack`, I set the `attackCooldown` to 10. But since `CooldownDuration` is set at the start, any change afterwards isn't computed.

Also, a lambda operator is a bit hairy for me yet.. Got this part from a tutorial.

I'd love to hear some ideas on how to tackle this!

The cooldown system that I got is from here, but since it doesn't account for variable times, I'm tweaking it a little bit.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zGvt4NnIYw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, the code should be:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var subAttack = new SubAttack();
        Console.WriteLine("Please Input CooldownDuration:");
        var input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        subAttack.PrintAttackCooldown();
        subAttack.PrintAttackCooldown(input);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


}

interface IHasCooldown
{
    int Id { get; }
    float CooldownDuration { get; }
}

class Attack : IHasCooldown
{
    public float attackCooldown { get; set; }
    int atkId = 2;
    public int Id => atkId;
    public float CooldownDuration => attackCooldown;
}

class SubAttack : Attack
{
    public void PrintAttackCooldown()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"CooldownDuration is {CooldownDuration}");
    }

    public void PrintAttackCooldown(int cooldown)
    {
        attackCooldown = cooldown;
        Console.WriteLine($"You Input CooldownDuration is {CooldownDuration}");
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Please Input CooldownDuration:
9
CooldownDuration is 0
You Input CooldownDuration is 9
```

Therefore, setting attackCooldown on SubAttack should be effective, and CooldownDuration will calculate the latest value each time it is used.

By the way:

```
public float CooldownDuration => attackCooldown equals public float CooldownDuration { get { return attackCooldown; } }
```

Comment: Thanks! As you said, it indeed should work... After adding some prints in the classes, it actually updates! The issue must be something on the cooldown system part. It's strange since I use the system in another class (not having variable cooldown duration) and no problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
public float CooldownDuration => attackCooldown;
```

Is a [**Property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). Without a lambda expression you could also write it as

```
public float CooldownDuration
{
    get { return attackCooldown; }
}
```

This is **not** set once but rather **always returns the current value of `attackCooldown`.**

---

Note though that the `attackCooldown` since it is also `public` and `get; set` is totally redundant. You could as well make it

```
public float CooldownDuration { get; set; }
```

and use that instead. The interface only defines the **minimum** requirements for a Property but it is allowed to also give it a setter even though it is not required by the interface.

If only your class shall be able to write to it you can also make it

```
public float CooldownDuration { get; private set; }
```

or if also subclasses shall be allowed to set the value

```
public float CooldownDuration { get; protected set; }
```